# How to execute JSONPath or XPATH expression on the Message Context property in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xpath, jsonpath, wso2-esb

I'm trying to set an Json object to a proerty using property mediator and then access the values of it using `JSONPath` or `XPATH`.

In this case, first I set the JSON Object to an OM typed property. In there, using `$ctx:parent/child pattern` I could access the values. But I can't execute the `XPath` expression over it (eg : `$ctx:metadataOM/suppliers[0]`).

I tried various scenarios and I noted that this can be done by setting that Json object to Payload and do `JSONpath` / `XPath` operations on it.

- Is there anyway to do this?
- Is there anyway to access the Message Context properties from `json-eval`?
- Is there anyway to execute the `JSONPath` / `XPATH` on `get-property` method or `$ctx:` expressions?

**Note :** I'm looking for an answer that doesn't use `Script medaitor` and `Class Mediator`.

**Payload :**

```
{ 
    "metadata":{ 
        "language":"en", 
        "customerCountry":"GB", 
        "client":"coolpal", 
        "suppliers" : ["supplier-a","supplier-b"], 
        "currency":"USD" 
    } 
}
```

**API.xml**

```
<inSequence>
    <property expression="//jsonObject/metadata" name="metadataOM" scope="default" type="OM"/>
    <property expression="//jsonObject/metadata" name="metadataSTR" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:metadataOM/suppliers" name="metadataOM-suppliers"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:metadataOM/suppliers[0]" name="metadataOM-suppliers"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.metadataOM.suppliers)" name="eval-metadata-suppliers"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.metadataSTR.suppliers)" name="eval-metadata-suppliers"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($ctx:metadataOM)" name="eval-metadata-suppliers"/>
    </log>
    <respond/>
</inSequence>
```

- WSO2ESB version : 5.0.0

Comment: You should be able to access the directly via e.g. $metadata.... See the follwoing link for details of the json path.            https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JSON+Support#JSONSupport-AccessingcontentfromJSONpayloads   In ESB 4.8.1 this also works    <property name="meta"
                                     expression="//metadata/text()"
                                     scope="default"
                                     type="STRING"/>

Comment: Thank you for the comment Martin. But this is working only for the JSON "payloads". Not for the Message Context properties.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question. You should be able to access message context in the way you already tried. In my proxies I use e.g. $ctx:proxy.name to get the actual proxy name. It should also be possible to access it when you do it like this get-property('axis2', propertyName)

Comment: Thanx Martin. I got it. Posted as an answer. Thanx again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

With Martin's help (Thanx Martin!) and some of self studies, I found an answer.

One reason was, when the json is connverted to the XML,it looks like below.

```
<metadata>
    <language>en</language>
    <customerCountry>GB</customerCountry>
    <client>coolpal</client>
    <suppliers>supplier-a</suppliers>
    <suppliers>supplier-b</suppliers>
    <currency>USD</currency>
</metadata>
```

Then I stored and loaded the first supplier as below. Second reason was, I forgot was suppliers are not zero indexed. :)

```
<property expression="/" name="metadataOM" scope="default" type="OM"/>

<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:metadataOM" name="metadataOM"/>
    <property expression="$ctx:metadataOM//jsonObject/metadata/suppliers[1]" name="metadataOM-supplier-1"/>
</log>
```